# javascript vs media queries

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm looking at creating a responsive framework for my website - its a first for me. No fancy stuff just responsive through mobile -> tablet -> desktop.

I'm happy with how media queries work, however adding classes through javascript seems like another viable option.

It would be easy to do something like this:

```
function queryViewport() {

    var $window = $(window);
    var $body = $("body");

    var windowWidth = $window.width();
    var windowHeight = $window.height();

    // Query window sizes to determine whether device is to be
    // classified as a small mobile device or a larger tablet/
    // desktop device.
    var isMobile = windowWidth < 600 || windowHeight < 600;

    $body.toggleClass("mobile", isMobile).toggleClass("desktop", !isMobile);

    // Calculate whether viewport is portrait or landscape
    var isPortrait = windowHeight > windowWidth;

    $body.toggleClass("portrait", isPortrait).toggleClass("landscape", !isPortrait);
}
```

However, I'm not an expert in this area - am I missing something or is it really that simple?

All advice appreciated.

Comment: This approach will work. I like that media queries stay with the CSS, where the rest of the formatting happens.

Comment: It is never that simple, since there are a plethora of widths ( and device-widths, watch the difference ) out there. I always advise http://mobiledetect.net.

Answer (score 2):

> you can use this minified jQuery snippet to detect if your user is
>   viewing using a mobile device. If you need to test for a specific
>   device I’ve included a collection of JavaScript snippets below which
>   can be used to detect various mobile handheld devices such as iPad,
>   iPhone, iPod, iDevice, Andriod, Blackberry, WebOs and Windows Phone.

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
   console.log("You are using a mobile device!");
}
else
{
   console.log("You are not using a mobile device!");
}
```

See more [DETECT MOBILE DEVICES USING JQUERY](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-detect-mobile-devices-using-jquery/)

See the link below to understand the difference

### [What is better: CSS media queries or JQuery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381321/what-is-better-css-media-queries-or-jquery-mobile)

Comment: This is for a JS library not bad, but never as complete as *http://mobiledetect.net*.

Comment: ``jQuery.browser.mobile`` More popular But your proposed library  also good.

Comment: The OP is asking about size targeting rather than device targeting.  I'm not sure suggesting a library to detect for mobile is relevant. Generally, websites should adapt visually based on size rather than device type.

Comment: @richieahb If you look carefully at the code
You will notice that he will realize that :
Mobile browser or other browsers

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest media queries, as all future amends can be done in the CSS without adding more and more logic to a separate JS file for new breakpoints.

Additionally, the CSS solution is supported down to IE9+ and there are JS polyfills ([Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)) for backwards compatibility.  Basically it's just built in to CSS and works well.  There seems little point of rewriting the same logic in javascript, having a new class for every new size.

On top of this, media queries allow you to target CSS as different media types such as print, or if you want to use height-based media queries or target retina displays you can do this without having to add new classes.  As a rule the convention is to use media queries with JS fallbacks and I see no reason to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

JS produces different results for detecting viewport heights and widths depending on how you get them:

In that case, you could get screen width using `window.outerWidth`, `window.innerWidth`, `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. All these produce different results, but the second will give you values identical to CSS `@media` breakpoint.

**`$(window).width()` too, is different from `@media` breakpoint.**

I depends on browser differences, e.g. if the take in account the vertical scrollbar or not. Better **go with CSS**.