# HTML layout changes with JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Should I change HTML layouts with JS or CSS?

I see a lot of use of CSS display hiding or showing elements dependent on media queries. Maybe hidden duplicate HTML that appears in a different location on mobile. A hidden mobile menu. Etc etc

But with JS i can have one layout that "morphs" dependent of screen width. No hidden duplicate markup, just moving HTML around.

Is this not a good idea?

Comment: "But with JS i can have one layout that "morphs" dependent of screen width. No hidden duplicate markup, just moving HTML around." — ahem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: It also depends on how much you move around? If it's one nav it's not that of a big deal. If it's like 5-10 elements, you should look into your design/talk to your designer first then trying to solve it with css or even js.

Answer (score 2):

Programatic changes on the layout will depend on the robustness and performance of your JS code.

CSS changes depends of the browser's and it's more efficient for sure.

About the enviroment's measure you can act upon them with css media-querys.

Comment: Yea the js approach is a bad idea. Performance wise and not to mention complexity and maintenance.

Comment: The performance is really good. Not huge changes. Quite minor. I just don't like duplicate HTML. Seems messy for updates.

Answer (score 0):

You should not forget, that some browsers/users disable JavaScript for security-reasons.
You should use CSS where it is possible. So your Website can be viewed in all Browsers.

If you have to change some styling dynamically, and there are no CSS-alternatives, javascrpit might be the right choice.

Comment: Thanks Phillip. The site I am developing has AJAX calls so wouldn't function without JS enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do, if it's basic animations, then css is here for you, if it's more advanced animations, then you should use JS, as other users said, keep in mind that some users disable JavaScript for security reasons, but i think they don't [exeed 5% of the users](https://blockmetry.com/blog/javascript-disabled) , here's some links to help you find out what's best for your use of css or JS :

[Myth Busting: CSS Animations vs. JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)
[CSS Versus JavaScript Animations](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/css-vs-javascript)

For media queries, here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381321/what-is-better-css-media-queries-or-jquery-mobile) that respond to your question. With the media queries, you won't have to hide anything, you will use a different CSS code for the same part of the HTML, but with different CSS attributes only for mobile/responsive use

For the SEO, here's and [experiment](https://www.elephate.com/blog/javascript-seo-experiment/) that shows that googleBots crawl the Js without problem.

**Edit** :  if you're able to use some server side language(php, asp...), use CSS for the design part, and the server side language for the other things, and only Javascript when you find it usefull. if you can do something with the CSS instead of JS, then do it with the CSS.

Comment: I use CSS for virtually everything Dhon. It was more a question of hiding duplicate HTML with CSS - and then showing it in mobile view - as position has changed. Or hiding/showing mobile/desktop menu.

Comment: for that, i think that using  the media queries [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) with CSS is better. with the media queries, you won't have to hide anything, you will use a different CSS code for the same part of the HTML, but with different CSS attributes only for mobile/responsive use